# How to use type hint to make sure two variables always have the same type?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have the following code

```
from typing import Union

def add(a: Union[int, str], b: Union[int, str]) -> str:
    return str(a) + str(b)

a: int = 1
b: int = 2
out = add(a, b)  # nice

a: str = 'one'
b: str = 'two'
out = add(a, b)  # nice

a: int = 1
b: str = 'two'
out = add(a, b)  # I hope the static check can raise error here when a and b are different types
```

I hope `mypy` can raise error for the third case. What should I do?

Comment: well, you could manually check in the function if the types of both variables are the same, a simple check: `if type(a) == type(b):`

Comment: Why is the third a problem, given the implementation? Also, why is the return type not just str? If you want a and b to always have the same type, why not use a [generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) or [overloads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)?

Comment: You want a type variable. `from typing import TypeVar`, then you can even constrain it, so you can do `T = TypeVar("T", str, int)` the use `def add(a: T, b: T) -> T: ...`

Comment: @Grismar the question is about mypy though, so it's for static analyisi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is the the `@overload` decorator, which lets you define specific combinations of arguments that are acceptable (with the implementation defined as a broader union type):

```
from typing import Union, overload


@overload
def add(a: int, b: int) -> str:
    pass


@overload
def add(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    pass


def add(a: Union[int, str], b: Union[int, str]) -> str:
    return f"{a}{b}"


add(1, 2)           # nice
add("one", "two")   # nice
add(1, "two")       # error: No overload variant of "add" matches argument types "int", "str"
```

Another option is a `TypeVar`:

```
from typing import TypeVar

A = TypeVar("A", str, int)


def add(a: A, b: A) -> str:
    return f"{a}{b}"


add(1, 2)           # nice
add("one", "two")   # nice
add(1, "two")       # error: Value of type variable "A" of "add" cannot be "object"
```

The error is a little more cryptic -- it's telling us that the nearest subtype of the two arguments (which is what `A` needs to correspond to) is `object`, and that `object` is too broad to satisfy the constraints placed on the definition of `A`.